# Is there a way to add a video to a Youtube playlist through Youtube API as a contributor?

Tags: javascript, api, youtube-api

I'm trying to add a video as a contributor through the Youtube API v3, but i keep getting `403 Forbidden` on the response, even though i'm a contributor to the playlist.

I know for a fact that the "contributor" part is the problem, because i can add any video to a playlist created by me, using the same exact method.

Here's the code im using (the same code in the [examples](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/javascript/playlist_updates.js)):

```
    function addToPlaylist(id, plid) {
        var details = {
            videoId: id,
            kind: 'youtube#video'
        }

        var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.insert({
            part: 'snippet',
            resource: {
                snippet: {
                    playlistId: plid,
                    resourceId: details
                }
            }
        });

        request.execute(function(response) {
            if (typeof response.code === 'undefined') {
                console.log("video added to playlist.");
            } else {
                console.log("error adding video to playlist.");
            }
        });
    }
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, based on the [YouTube Data API Errors](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors), the `error 403 or forbidden error` means that the access is forbidden or the request may not be properly authorized. So it seems that only the owner of the playlist can only do this operation.

Check these SO questions if it can help you.

- [403 Forbidden Youtube API playlist item insert using API explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848268/403-forbidden-youtube-api-playlist-item-insert-using-api-explorer)
- [Insert video into someone else's playlist YouTube API v3 results in 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36120734/insert-video-into-someone-elses-playlist-youtube-api-v3-results-in-403)